# SEXTANTE toolbox - GRASS error

Tags: grass-gis, vector, sextante

I am trying to use the SEXTANTE module GRASS (and SAGA) for vector analysis but whatever function I use I always get the same error:"Could not load layer: G:/closest.shp
Check the SEXTANTE log to look for errors in algorithm execution"

SEXTANTE log says (for "v.distance" module):
"Sextante.runalg("grass:v.distance","G:/For QGIS/example_1/point.shp","G:/For QGIS/example_1/point_II.shp",1,"col_name","id",False,False,"G:/closest.shp")"

I get this on three different computers with QGIS 1.8.0., SEXTANTE 1.0.7., updated Win 7.

I think this question is the similar problem:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24895/qgis-sextante-doesnt-create-load-output

Comment: Is G:/ writable for you? Maybe the TMP file settings in the plugin are wrong?

Comment: Yes "G:/" is writable. I get the same error no matter what hard disk or partition is used.

Comment: Is this still an issue after updating to the latest version?

Comment: Removing spaces in your path _might_ help - those are known to cause problems sometimes. You can use underscores instead of spaces to test it out, so rename "For QGIS" -> "For_QGIS".

Comment: There can probably be many reasons for your problems.  But since your example is v.distance, I would like you to know that v.distance is currently not working through QGIS processing.  See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73575/grass-in-qgis-not-working-windows-xp

Comment: Sextante is replaced by processing. Sorry for me. :( I can't get SAGA to work with the old question and answers on help sites.

Answer (score 2):

I get the same type of result when there is no file produced at the end of a process.

In some cases it is because there is no data because I have input the wrong layers or the layers in the wrong order.

In other cases it is because I don't have read / write for all the necessary directories.  My installation of QGIS 2.2 has different permissions to my installation of QGIS 2.4 (an IT thing that is irrelevant here). But what that means is that I have two sets of algorithms listed under the Processing Toolbox. They look identical, one set will produce that error because of the permissions, the other will produce a result.

I just need to remember which set will give me a result.